# How to parse multiple pdf conversion into hadoop (example)

Tags: hadoop, pdf, analytics

i have one million pdf , how to convert into text using hadoop and used this for analytics.
The goal is to use the power of hadoop for extracting pdf data as a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have processed a single pdf file on Hadoop not tried with multiple file but i believe it will work fine for multiple files too..

Complete code is available on the below link

http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/12/poc-sensex-log-data-processing-pdf-file.html

**Hope this helps!!..**